# Can I extract common things from different properties files?

Tags: java, properties

I am writing in java. Now I am in the situation, when I have two files with properties. First file is for stand and second file is for my PC. And they different just in one line. But maybe in the future it will be more difference between them. Can I do something to extract common things to third file or something like this and use it in both of my properties. For example, user’s names and passwords in these files are the same. And when in app changes some of passwords, I need to change it in both of my property files. Can I do something that will be store passwords, and link my property files to this?

Comment: Cna be done with `maven-assembly-plugin`. Or you just read multiple property files

Answer (score 0):

I have done next things. I have created new property file with user’s names and passwords, then create new class, and in this class I read this new property file and put values in static HashMaps LOGIN and PASSWORD. Now I can store passwords in one place and use it in different environments